# How to force Python emcee to move sampler with a certain step

Tags: python, mcmc, emcee

I run emcee sampler like:

```
p0 = sampler.run_mcmc(p0, conf_res['niter_burn'], progress=True)
```

Where p0 is a list of starting values for each variable parameter

```
p0 = [
        np.array([randrange_float(var['min_val'], var['max_val'], var['step']) for var in 
        conf_res['var_params_list']]) for i in range(nwalkers)
    ]
```

It is calculating with randrange_float func:

```
def randrange_float(start, stop, step):
    """
    usage:
        randrange_float(2.1, 4.2, 0.3) # returns 2.4
    Args:
        start: min value
        stop: max value
        step: step size
    Return:
        float: random in the given range of values
    """
    return random.randint(0, int((stop - start) / step)) * step + start
```

Everything works fine, my starting parameters are without float part (except first one) because my step is 1.0.

```
Starting Values of Parameters:
#      P      P_phase      P_pr     Pr_phase    Pr_angle 
     40.83      91.00    2720.00     336.00      -6.00
     40.84     222.00    1940.00      35.00       1.00
     40.44     270.00    2540.00     242.00     -13.00
     40.83     145.00    2450.00      59.00      -5.00
     40.46     251.00    2330.00     106.00       8.00
.... nwalker times...
```

But when emcee sampler moved away from starting values (*p0*), I got parameters with float step.
Is there a way to defile the step for emcee walker? 
 **emcee.EnsembleSampler** has *moves* parameter. Do I have to write my version of *Move class*? I can't understand what Mover class should return.

Comment: any ideas? I'm stuck ...